# Sortable jQuery drag div into td

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my project I'm trying to do a sortable table.
I tried much, but no solution was found.

Question 1: I can't drag a div to an empty td.
Question 2: I try to get data from a data attribute while dragging. (this) wont work...

my JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aq98v/6/

here is the code below:

Javascript:

```
$(function(){   
    $("#dropable").sortable({
        items : ".drag",
        start: function() {
            displayValue(this);
        },
        stop: function() {
            hideValue();
        },
        receive: function() {
            dropped(this);
        }
    });
});

function toggleNumbers(e) {
    var time = $(e).data("time");
    var visitor = $(e).data("visitor");
    $(".lol").html("selected time ="+time+" selected visitor ="+visitor);
}

function hideValue() {
    $(".lol").html("Reboot");
}

function dropped(e) {
    var time = $(e).data("time");
    var visitor = $(e).data("visitor");
    $(".lol").html("Success Dropped!!! time ="+time+" And visitor ="+visitor);
}
```

html is very long in JSfiddle. i do a short one here.

```
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr><th class="col-lg-1">Monday</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="dropable">
        <tr class="droping">
            <td>
                <div class="drag" data-time="09:00" data-visitor="12">
                    <span class="time">09:00</span>
                    <span class="visitor">12</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/aq98v/22/

```
$(function(){   
        $(".droping").sortable({
                 connectWith:"td",
                 placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        }).disableSelection();
});
```